# What is the point of the "Small Final" in Snowboard Cross?

Tags: olympics, snowboarding

Last night I watched the women's snowboard cross event of the 2018 PyeongChang Winter Olympics.

After the semifinal races and before the final race (officially known as the "Big Final"), NBC showed what they called a consolation race - the "[Small Final](https://www.olympic.org/pyeongchang-2018/results/en/snowboard/results-ladies-snowboard-cross-fnl-000200-.htm)".  This race included the 4th through 6th place finishers of the two semifinal races.

I know some events will have a consolation match that determines who wins the bronze medal.  But this "Small Final" race determined who finished in 7th through 12th place.  What is the point of that?  Why does it matter who finishes in 7th through 12th place?

Comment: Was coming in to ask that same question. Woo. You get into the small final and can get as high as 7th place. When your olympic dreams just got crushed, I don't see much of a point. Theory: The event still gives point for the world championship/season of snowboard cross, so 7-12 place is still relevant, but not for the olympics per say.

Comment: And people WANT to still race the small final. In the Mens Snowboard cross, one guy had his hand bandaged in place so he could run it. I mean, it can be fun to run one more run in the olympics, but if my hand was killing me because of a bad fall, and had no chance of medal in that run, I would just call it a day.

Comment: @Fredy31 Your first comment is enough of an answer to post as one, in my opinion.

Comment: @user257138 Only if it is verified that the small final is indeed relevant to the snowboard cross season.

Comment: Exactly. Sports seems to be kinda lax on that kind of thing, but I'm coming from Gaming, and there, well if you don't have some hard evidence, you're gonna be crucified :p

Comment: @pacoverflow Missed the word "Theory." Good point.

Comment: @Fredy31 I don't think Sports is lax on this at all.  I come across multiple answers with comments asking for sources for findings, but as I stated, I missed the word "Theory" and thought that was the reason why. My bad. https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17551/why-did-neymar-join-psg-given-how-good-his-previous-club-is/17555#comment27837_17555 https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17562/can-a-forward-pass-be-thrown-after-a-handoff-made-in-front-of-the-quarterback/17563#comment27853_17563

Comment: Yup we kind of commented at the same moment lol

Comment: the top 8 finishers still get oympic diplomas so they need a way to determine placement. additionally there might be tour points given out at the olympic tournament and therefore again need placement races

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that the Small Final would matter in the rare situation that 4 or more competitors in the Big Final are disqualified.  If that happened, then they would award the remaining medal(s) to the top finisher(s) of the Small Final.

This situation happened yesterday in the [Women's Short Track Speed Skating 3000M Relay](https://www.olympic.org/news/republic-of-korea-win-gold-in-women-s-3-000m-team-relay).  Four teams participated in the main final (the "A Final").  However, two of those teams ended up being disqualified, so they awarded the bronze medal to the winning team of the "B Final", which had been run to determine 5th through 8th place.

Answer (score 0):

At the Olympics those who come 4-8th receive Olympic diplomas. I am guessing it is proof that you are in the top 8 of your sport, so it matters for sponsorship etc...

Comment: But there are other events that do not know who came in 5th, 6th, 7th, or 8th place.

Comment: they do know who came in those places. they might not have an extra competition but they have ways of determining the top 8.